# MYSQL: How to get the current entry of multipe tables

Tags: mysql

I got three tables with data for products:
One where the products are defined.
A second where is defined which store has what products with what priceing with a timestamp.
And a third with the stock in the store of the products that are assiged.

```
Table 1 - products:
prdoductID|Name
----------|-------
1         |banana
2         |apple

Table 2 - prices:
storeID | productID | price | timestamp
--------|-----------|-------|------------
1       | 1         | 5,90  | 2016-03-27 16:00:00
1       | 1         | 5,90  | 2016-03-27 17:00:00
2       | 1         | 5,00  | 2016-03-27 16:00:00
2       | 2         | 5,00  | 2016-03-27 16:00:00
2       | 2         | 5,90  | 2016-03-28 19:00:00

Table 3 - stocks:
storeID | productID | stock | timestamp
--------|-----------|-------|------------
1       | 1         | 50    | 2016-03-27 08:00:00
1       | 1         | 5     | 2016-03-27 17:00:00
2       | 1         | 60    | 2016-03-27 09:00:00
2       | 2         | 0     | 2016-03-27 16:00:00
2       | 2         | 55    | 2016-03-28 19:00:00
```

`
Now I want to get the current state of one store for example at time 2016-03-27 14:00:00.

My current query get's for me the data but for all timestamps. I just want to get the corresponding entrys with the recent timesamps for each product of this store with the storeID = x;

Note: The user is able to plan. So there could be entries with futre timestamps so just a MAX would not work.

```
Query:
SELECT price.*, prod.name, stock.timestamp as 'stockTimesamp',
stock.stock FROM prices price 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products prod on price.productID = prod.productID and 
price.timestamp=(SELECT MAX(price.timestamp) WHERE price.timestamp <= '2016-03-27 14:00:00' and price.productID = prod.productID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN stocks stock on price.storeID = best.storeID and price.productID = stock.productID and stock.timestamp=(SELECT MAX(best.timestamp) WHERE stock.timestamp <= '2016-03-27 14:00:00' and stock.productID = prod.productID and stock.productID = price.productID) 
where price.storeID=21
ORDER BY stock.timestamp DESC
```

Hope you can help me out...

Answer (score 0):

This is a troublesome data structure for this type of query.  You can get the most recent timestamp per product for each table and then join back to get additional information:

```
select p.*,
       (select max(timestamp)
        from stocks s
        where s.storeid = $storeid and s.productid = p.productid and
              s.timestamp <=  '2016-03-27 14:00:00'
      ) as stock_timestamp,
       (select max(timestamp)
        from prices pr
        where pr.storeid = $storeid and pr.productid = p.productid and
              pr.timestamp <=  '2016-03-27 14:00:00'
      ) as stock_timestamp     
from products p;
```

Then, join back to the original tables to get additional information:

```
select p.*, s.*, pr.*
from (select p.*,
             (select max(timestamp)
              from stocks s
              where s.storeid = $storeid and s.productid = p.productid and
                    s.timestamp <=  '2016-03-27 14:00:00'
            ) as stock_timestamp,
             (select max(timestamp)
              from prices pr
              where pr.storeid = $storeid and pr.productid = p.productid and
                    pr.timestamp <=  '2016-03-27 14:00:00'
            ) as price_timestamp     
      from products p
     ) p left join
     stocks s
     on s.storeid = $storeid and s.productid = p.productid and
        s.timestamp = p.stock_timestamp left join
     prices pr
     on pr.storeid = $storeid and pr.productid = p.productid and
        pr.timestamp = p.price_timestamp ;
```

I should note that your problem would be relatively trivial if you had an effective and end date on each record.  That is a better way to store a slowly changing dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have some references to this topic because your code is throwing some errors, respectively I've never saw such a sub-request in the main select section.

Comment: @OliverBecker . . . This uses subqueries which are a standard part of the SQL language.  It is hard to suggest improvements unless you specify the error.